# How can I convert a number into an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion, integer

I want to convert a number into an array. Basically, I want to convert

`x=0`

to

`x=[0]`

and I do not know if there is a simplified Python shortcut or function I can use.

Comment: `[0]` is a list.

Comment: perhaps `x = [x]`?

Comment: Don't think of it as converting a number, but rather, "how to make a list containing the number".  `[]` is **the** way of making a list.  But if what you really want is a `numpy`, array, the `numpy` documentation has that covered.  If you don't like these answers, you'll need to explain in more depth that you really need.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this in python is what you suggested:

```
x = [0]
```

Comment: Thats not what I meant tho. Given x = 0, convert it into x = [0]. Basically, I want to find a function that can do that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
list = []
list.append(0)
```